# SpringBoot : Testing a service with Constructor Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, junit4

I have a SpringBoot app (REST Architecture )
I have this service defined that uses Constructor Dependency Injection

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class HostelService {

    private final HostelRepository hostelRepository;

    HostelService(HostelRepository hostelRepository) {
        this.hostelRepository = hostelRepository;
    }
}
```

I want to use it in a integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class HostelServiceIntegrationTest {

    public static final String Hostel_1 = "Hostel::1";

    @Autowired
    protected HostelRepository hostelRepository;

    @Autowired
    private HostelService hostelService;


    //...
}

@Repository
public interface HostelRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Hostel, String> {

}
```

but I have this error:

> `..Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;`

Caused by:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
>       No qualifying bean of type 'io.clouding.repository.HostelRepository' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}

and on the Application:

```
@SpringCloudApplication
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("io.clouding.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "io.clouding.repository" })
public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {
..
}
```

Comment: Does `HostelRepository` have any explicit dependencies that need to be satisfied?

Comment: you need to show the error message completely

Comment: Seems like the HostelRepository is not on the testing context.

Comment: Mock the repository instead of autowiring it `@MockBean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your problem is that your bean, `HostelRespository` is not getting created. And it's a `CouchbaseRepository`. I hope it's not even created in non-test environment also.

What you have to do is, ***instead*** of

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("io.clouding.repository")
```

***add***

```
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {"io.clouding.repository"})
```

It will help run-time to create the bean for you. So your specific problem will be solved.

**Note**:

Please note that, if you haven't still configured the underlying configurations needed for `spring-data-couchbase`, you might see some other errors after fixing this, that you have to fix by configuration. You may refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-couchbase).

Answer (score 0):

**The error says it,** you probably have a RequestRepository and the error is inside it; check the constructor/dependencies in it and see if something is not being injected or ***show*** the RequestRepository and the full error stack trace.

Comment: IMHO this is not a solution to the question but a request for more info from OP.